# run all tests that cover this method/class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, resharper, dotcover

One thing I repeatedly do after I made changes to a method is I quickly want to run all the tests that cover this method.

Do you know of a tool that gives me this very button/menu entry? *run tests that affect this method* and *run tests that affect this class*?

I have dotCover and ReShaper installed but I don't see an option like that anywhere.

I know there continuos testing tools like NCrunch or Mighty Moose that constantly run all my tests in the background but I am not sure I am ready for these yet.

Comment: If you have partitioned your tests correctly, e.g. all tests for a specific behavior live in a class/package of classes and they are all fast.. you can run a subset. Not a big fan of Test Impact, but it seems to be what you want.. I'd rather work on getting the entire suite to execute within minutes on a well-spec-ed laptop. I was watching a video yesterday where Uncle Bob shows the entire suite for Fitnesse (unit+acceptance) completes within 4 minutes.. 2 on a laptop with SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have partitioned your tests correctly, e.g. all tests for a specific behavior live in a class/package of classes and they are all fast.. you can run a subset. Not a big fan of MS Test Impact for unit tests, but it seems to be what you want. (It'd been awesome for end to end tests but sadly doesn't work yet)

I'd rather work on getting the entire suite to execute within minutes on a well-spec-ed laptop. I want to be running all my tests with every change (the only optimization I'd like is to run the failing tests from the previous run first - some tools support this).
I just watched a NDC Oslo video where Uncle Bob shows the entire suite for Fitnesse (unit+acceptance) completes within 4 minutes.. 2 on a laptop with SSD.

Answer (score 5):

1. According to [this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-3313), Jetbrains will add this feature in one of
   their next releases.
2. You can try Microsoft's [Test Impact Analysis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2009/12/07/test-impact-analysis-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx), but I believe it supports only MSTest (Supposedly it'l change in VS2012).
3. [Typemock Isolator 7](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) has this feature, called AutoRunner.

Disclosure: I used to work for Typemock.